# Troubleshooting simple transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, npn

[image]

I tried making a simple circuit as shown above. The battery BT1 is a 12V DC power adapter. D1 is actually about 6 LEDs in series. For R1, I tried 47 Ohm, 470 Ohm, 1K Ohm, etc., but D1 never turns on.

The circuit below works. BT2 is 12V, and battery BT3 is 5V, or even a 3V battery works, the D2 LEDs turn on.

The transistor I used was a D882 and a 2N2222.
(I did not try  2N2219, I apologize for the misleading diagram, that is all I could find in KiCad, I am new to all this.)

Shouldn't the first circuit work? Why does it not turn the LED on?

[image]

============================

Update: I tried the following also after reading the answer. Still the LED's did not turn on.

[image]

Next I am trying to figure out how to simulate this in Kicad to see what I am doing wrong. But if anyone has any tips, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: From your words I estimate that D1 is now destroyed due to excessive over-current. LEDs require current limiting circuits and, I don't know how many posts there are on this site about this but, there are probably dozens.

Comment: What colour LEDs?

Comment: The LED's are yello
D1 is not destroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory the circuit with two batteries really shouldn't work if you're using six LEDs in an emitter follower circuit.

For the transistor to turn on you need the base to be around 0.6 V above the voltage at the emitter. The emitter voltage is going to be the voltage across the LEDs and with six of them that should be at least 6 V or more depending on the LED color, so a 5 V battery probably isn't going to get the base voltage high enough and a 3 V battery should be far below what's needed.

Simulating that circuit in LTspice I get less than 1 uA of LED current with six LEDs dropping 0.6 V each (which I think is being generous) and a 3.3 V battery on the base. With 5 V the voltage increased to just under 0.9 V per LED and the current was under 10 uA.

That is of course theory, and sometimes circuits don't do what theory says they should, so maybe it sort of works for some unknown reason, but I suspect there's something amiss here, perhaps the transistor is damaged and leaky, maybe you didn't actually use six LEDs when testing it.

Now that all said, the better way to do this kind of circuit is common emitter. Put the LEDs on the collector side with a current limiting resistor, ground the emitter and use a current limiting resistor on the base. This way you'll only need around 0.6 V to turn the transistor on.